# R: Using cut on a data frame in R, with different breakpoints for each column

Tags: r

I am trying to factorize a data frame, where the cut-offs would be min, median, max of each variable (column).

I have managed to do so, by creating a data frame "cuts" in which the respective values are stored, and using a for loop afterwards. However, I feel like it could be done more elegantly. Any idea would be welcome!

A reproducible example follows:

```
# Sample data frame
mydf <- na.omit(airquality)[1:20,1:4]

# Break points
cuts<-rbind(sapply(mydf,min),sapply(mydf,median),sapply(mydf,max))

# Data frame to keep factors
mydf.bin <- mydf

for (i in 1:ncol(mydf)) {
  mydf.bin[,i]<-cut(mydf[,i],cuts[,i],include.lowest=T)
}

mydf.bin

#I am looking for something like the following, except each column should have different break points
mybindf<-sapply(mydf, cut, c(0,50,350), include.lowest=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use an anonymous function?

```
mybindf <- sapply(mydf, function(x) {
    cuts <- c(min(x), median(x), max(x))
    cut(x, cuts, include.lowest = TRUE)
})
```

Better practice in this case might be to define the function separately, which makes for easier debugging and more readable code:

```
cut_min_med_max <- function(x) {
    cuts <- c(min(x), median(x), max(x))
    cut(x, cuts, include.lowest = TRUE)
}
mybindf <- sapply(mydf, cut_min_med_max)
```

The only difference between these solutions and your solution is that you generate the cut points separately from making the cuts, while here everything happens at once.

And for completeness, your original code can be vectorized:

```
mybindf <- as.data.frame(
    mapply(cut, mydf, cuts, MoreArgs = list(include.lowest = TRUE))
)
```

although you could just as easily have dropped both steps into the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. The initial idea was indeed to generate cuts simultaneously, but I got carried away trying to find a solution. I prefer the separate function, too.

Comment: Yup, I don't know what your background is, but mine certainly wasn't computer science when I started learning R. I had to learn a lot of stuff the hard way, like how not to overcomplicate everything.

Comment: My background is mathematical-statistical. Although I like coding, it's actually hard to do it the right way, because you always try to figure out solutions while pursuing something else, thus missing the beauty of programming. But time makes one better, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bin` function from the [OneR package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=OneR):

```
library(OneR)

# Sample data frame
mydf <- na.omit(airquality)[1:20,1:4]

# bin function is an enhanced version of cut for data frames
mydf.bin <- bin(mydf, nbins = 2, method = "content")

mydf.bin
##        Ozone    Solar.R        Wind      Temp
## 1    (15,41]  (170,334] (7.39,11.5] (64.5,74]
## 2    (15,41] (7.67,170] (7.39,11.5] (64.5,74]
## 3  (0.96,15] (7.67,170] (11.5,20.1] (64.5,74]
## 4    (15,41]  (170,334] (7.39,11.5] (57,64.5]
## 7    (15,41]  (170,334] (7.39,11.5] (64.5,74]
## 8    (15,41] (7.67,170] (11.5,20.1] (57,64.5]
## 9  (0.96,15] (7.67,170] (11.5,20.1] (57,64.5]
## 12   (15,41]  (170,334] (7.39,11.5] (64.5,74]
## 13 (0.96,15]  (170,334] (7.39,11.5] (64.5,74]
## 14 (0.96,15]  (170,334] (7.39,11.5] (64.5,74]
## 15   (15,41] (7.67,170] (11.5,20.1] (57,64.5]
## 16 (0.96,15]  (170,334] (7.39,11.5] (57,64.5]
## 17   (15,41]  (170,334] (11.5,20.1] (64.5,74]
## 18 (0.96,15] (7.67,170] (11.5,20.1] (57,64.5]
## 19   (15,41]  (170,334] (7.39,11.5] (64.5,74]
## 20 (0.96,15] (7.67,170] (7.39,11.5] (57,64.5]
## 21 (0.96,15] (7.67,170] (7.39,11.5] (57,64.5]
## 22 (0.96,15]  (170,334] (11.5,20.1] (64.5,74]
## 23 (0.96,15] (7.67,170] (7.39,11.5] (57,64.5]
## 24   (15,41] (7.67,170] (11.5,20.1] (57,64.5]
```

NB: the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range to ensure that the extreme values both fall within the break intervals as is standard behaviour of the `cut` function.

(Full discosure: I am the author of this package)